# Setting Viewport on Google Maps when sending several addresses

Tags: google-maps

I have code where I would like to send several addresses to google maps. However, since I'm doing this a a series of geocodings, how can I make the viewport at least center and zoom correctly on the group?

```
function doBatchGeocodeAndSearch() {
$('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');

var lines = $('#styled').val().split('\n');

for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': lines[i]}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport); 
        // map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(),
        // map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the map.setCenter call.  The last call to map.fitBounds will show all the markers, if there is only one marker, will zoom in really close though, may want to handle that specially.

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': lines[i]}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
```